# How to professionally tell employees he/she should ask you for assistance/guidance?

Tags: professionalism

I am charge of several SharePoint environments. Currently, there are people who support and build solutions with SharePoint for business units, like me--and others, which I have no jurisdiction over in other departments and business units, that will build a solution with no best practice or programming mindset in place. It's analogous to putting duct tape on airplane wings. Things they have been doing are cringe-worthy to look at.

How do I let these users know that I have extensive experience with SharePoint without making it seem like I am telling them how to do their job--of which I have no authority to?

Comment: There needs to be some manager in charge of SharePoint dev. Talk to them inquire if they have a set of coding standards set up. If they don't ask if you can set one up, as you have noticed a lot of variance between the different solutions deployed.

Answer (score 8):

### Start a Developer Group

Start a SharePoint Developer Group at the Company.

Announce for the good of the company that you're forming a user's group to allow all of the SharePoint developers to help each other and improve the overall success of the organization in this area.

Detail your history and skills in the announcement and your willingness to help solve problems, offer advice on best practices and willingness to review folks work to see how it could be improved.

Even if nobody shows up or shows interest, you still have:

1. Made your skills known,
2. Shown that you are a team player looking out for the greater good of the organization,
3. Shown that you are self-starter and leader.

When the time comes when management realizes they have a mess on their hands (and it will), they will know who to turn to.

Comment: Worth while to note, that if/when it comes to "management realiz[ing] they have a mess on their hands"...do you want to be the one there cleaning it up after the fact when it did not need to happen in the first place? Management not realizing the issues occurring when they show-up vs blow-up is an interesting sign.

Answer (score 2):

### Reach out to someone who has the authority.

Depending on your company's size, there should be someone in charge of "best practices", be it a dedicated role or simply a part of a high-level manager's  responsibilities.

Either way, reach out to that person and state your concerns, give examples with arguments (obviously without pointing fingers at peoples), and offer your help (suggest Priz's solution, training,...)

This way, you can initiate an official and enforced "sharepoint best practice policy" in your company, and keep on working cringelessly. Be prepared, however, to become THE Sharepoint good practice reference.

Answer (score -2):

Inform your manager and let them decide if they want to follow up on it.